# Применение изменений в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Я совсем новичок в Vue, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой - когда я вношу какие либо изменения в код то для их применения приходится заново пересобирать билд (npm run build) и обновлять страницу. Это жутко неудобно и тратит много времени. Я точно знаю что применяться изменения в коде могут сразу после сохранения (Ctrl+s) но вот не знаю как это сделать.
Если подскажите как добиться применения без повторной сборки или подскажите где можно почитать то буду очень благодарен

Vue 2.6.11

Answer (score 0):

[vue-cli-service serve](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve)

Если Вы загляните в Ваш package.json, то скорее всего увидите эту команду в свойстве `scripts`.

Рекомендую для начала ознакомиться с документацией `vue-cli-service`, в ссылке выше.

[image: vue-cli-service serve]

Answer (score 0):

Если запускать проект npm run serve, то не потребуется сборка, перезапуск должен производится автоматически после сохранения.